# How to resolve the error: Argument 2 passed to t() must be of the type array, null given, called in rules.core.inc

Tags: commerce

A Drupal Commerce site is giving from time to time the following error on /cart page:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to t() must be of the type array, null        
given, called in 
/home/username/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/includes/rules.core.inc 
on line 2676 in t() (line 1720 of 
/home/username/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

I tried to put the `dpm(ddebug_backtrace(TRUE));` just before the line 1720 in bootstrap.inc file, but the website goes blank. Devel module is of course enabled.

The website's error log show:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ddebug_backtrace() in /home/username/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc:1720
mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:
mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /home/username/public_html/index.php(19): require_once()
mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 {main}
mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /home/username/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1720
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ddebug_backtrace() in /home/username/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc:1720, referer: https://website.com/admin/reports/dblog
mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: https://website.com/admin/reports/dblog
mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /home/username/public_html/index.php(19): require_once(), referer: https://website.com/admin/reports/dblog
mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 {main}, referer: https://website.com/admin/reports/dblog
mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /home/username/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1720, referer: https://website.com/admin/reports/dblog
```

I believe one of the Rules is faulty, but the website has so many of them that it would be nice to trace which one first. And then I can't why `ddebug_backtrace` does not work. Any hints appreciated.

Edit: Reported this on Rules module's issue queue: [Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1836 of /bootstrap.inc)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2778663). But the error is still there.

Comment: Have you enabled the debug message of rules? It would provide more details.

Comment: The first error message is actually from Rules debug.

Comment: If `ddebug_backtrace()` does not work, you can try `var_dump(debug_backtrace);`. It should work.

Comment: `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` I forget to add the brackets....